# How to get child objects field in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I writing a django app and I need to access child objects field in admin and templates:
my models:

```
class House(models.Model):
    doc_code = models.IntegerField()
    ...
    def getGuardian(self):
       guardian = self.person_set.filter(membership=1)
       return guardian
    def __str__(self):
       return "Family: " + str(self.doc_code)
class Person(models.Model):
    family = models.ForeignKey(House)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...
def __str__(self):
    return self.last_name + ' ' + self.first_name
```

in view:

```
houses = House.objects.order_by('doc_code')
```

in template:

```
<li>{{house.doc_code}} {{house.getGuardian}}</li>
```

I receive:

```
1 [<Person: Smith John>]
```

How can I get rid of "[ < Person:....> ]" and just display the name?
Also how can I change the title of field getGuardian in Admin Page?

Comment: I dont know if the code is just wrongly copy-pasted, but the second method __str__() is not properly intended, so it does not belong to the model now

Comment: just copy  paste, an I can not intend id here :)

Comment: What you mean you can not? You have to, otherwise the string representation of the model would be generic which is your problem atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you don't want it to show up in brackets `[]`, you need to return a single object, instead of a list. If the query for guardian will always return a single member, you could do something like

```
def getGuardian(self):
    guardian = self.person_set.get(membership=1)
    return guardian
```

And guardian will be a single `Person` object.

Second, to change the representation from `<Person: Smith John>` to just `Smith John`, you should customize the `__repr__` method of your model, rather than the `__str__` method:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.last_name + ' ' + self.first_name
```

I am not sure if you really want to do that, because it will make these objects appear as strings, which may be misleading in some cases, but that is up to you. You might be better off getting the guardian's name in your view and passing it to the context, or just have `getGuardian` return the name of the guardian to begin with:

```
def getGuardianName(self):
    guardian = self.person_set.get(membership=1)
    return str(guardian)
```